# Facebook Graph Api secure calls with Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, reactjs, ecmascript-6, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have a web app that is fetching the latest post from a public Facebook Page, and displaying it with the post's background image. It works localhosted, but the access_token is displaying it's full glory in Chrome Developer tools. This is of course bad practice, and I'm looking for ways to securely request the access_token from the server/external service.

The point of the app is to be able to fetch the information from the facebook page without requesting a user login from the client. As of now, I understand that it requires an admin access_token in order to fetch the info, but maybe I'm wrong here? Is there an easier way to just fetch the latest post info from a public facebook page? I don't completely understand why Facebook requires an admin token to fetch publicly available info?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't completely understand why Facebook requires an admin token to fetch publicly available info?

Facebook doesn't want anonymous requests to their API. That's why an access token is required.

> The point of the app is to be able to fetch the information from the facebook page without requesting a user login from the client.

You will still need an access token. But like you said, it's not a good idea to request it on the client since it requires your secrets. So, you'll have to go server-side with this (e.g. NodeJS). Make a request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=client_credentials
```

and then send either the token or the already fetched data to the client. You could set up your own API for this, actually.

Otherwise you could look into scraping the posts with CasperJS or similar, not a great developer experience though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Fabian. I guess I'll go the NodeJS-way and figure this out!